# Find Username and Password Elements In An Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

Is there a way where a user inputs 2 values like 'username' and 'password'. Can I then check the array to see if these elements are present and then grant the user access? If they are granted access it would print out there admin rights: `print('admin')` or `print('user')`

Array:

```
myArray = ['bob', '123', 'admin',
          'sam', 'qwerty', 'user']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need to do is check if the user is in your user list and make sure the password matches the username. To do that, dictionaries would be best. This way, you can match the password with the username.

```
users = {'bob': 'pass', '123': 'pass', 'admin': 'pass',
         'sam': 'pass', 'qwerty': 'pass', 'user': 'pass'}
```

Here you set the users and their passwords into a dictionary, you can preset this or you can have a function to create a new user which will be added to the dictionary. A dictionary basically just associates two key values to each other. Ex: (one: 1, two: 2)

```
login = input("Enter username: ")
password = input("Enter password: ")
```

Here you're simply setting the variables login and password to user input.

```
if login in users and users[login] == password:
    print("Login successful!")
else:
    print("Login invalid")
```

Finally, here you're checking to see if what the user inputted is in the dictionary of users and passwords. If whatever the user inputs, whether it be username or password, isn't in the dictionary then they will get the login invalid.

I hope this helped you. There are ways to allow the user to create a new profile, if you want to know how to do that just let me know! If you get stuck or don't understand anything I just said, I will of course verify and answer any questions.

Comment: When I enter 'bob' and his password '123', I get an invalid login. I tried this with sam and his password but still got the same. Have you tried this code? If so is it the same?

Comment: Yes I tried it, the problem could be that the input is being read as an int 123 rather than a string '123'. Try to change input to raw_input... input takes in all types of data types while raw input takes in only string. So if you type 123 into input, it'll be set to the number 123... If you type 123 into raw_input, it'll be set to a string '123'. I hope that clarifies everything!

Comment: Still Doesn't work... Here's what I am using raw_input didn't work and says it is not defined here is the code I'm using: ```users = {'bob': 'pass', '123': 'pass', 'admin': 'pass',
         'sam': 'pass', 'qwerty': 'pass', 'user': 'pass'}

login = str(input("Enter username: "))
password = str(input("Enter password: "))

if login in users and users[login]  ==  password:
    print("Login successful!")
else:
    print("Login invalid")```

Comment: This is because Bob's password isn't 123: 
```
    users = {**'bob':'pass'**, '123':'pass', 'admin':'pass', 
                  'sam':'pass', 'qwerty':'pass', 'user':'pass' }
```
bobs password is 'pass', '123' is another user... Make sure to pay attention to the commas and colons. 'bob':'pass' The colon is what connects the 2 keys and the comma separates the sets of keys

Comment: This Works Now! I am very sorry for all the confusion, I am not used to dictionaries and I thought that the 'pass' was required in a dictionary. Thank you for all your help and not giving up on me as other people would!!  :)                                                                          ***Please could you provide the code to add another user for future reference. Thanks!***

Comment: No problem! Learn more about dictionaries here: https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Comment: `users = {}
status = input('Do you have an account? ')

if status == 'n':
    newUser = input('Create a username: ')

    if createLogin in users:
        print('Username already taken')
    else:
        createPassword = input('Create Password: ')
        users[newUser] = createPassword
        print('User created!')

    elif status == 'y':
        login = input("Enter username: ")
        if login in users:
            password = input("Enter password: ")

                if login in users and password in users:
                    print("Login Success")
        else:`